# Reduce array to sub-array in O(n)

Tags: typescript, algorithm, tree

Consider data source:

```
const data: InfoNode[] = [
    {
        parentId: '7',
        id: '1',
        name: 'Harry'
    },
    {
        parentId: '7',
        id: '2',
        name: 'Hermoine'
    },
    {
        parentId: '7',
        id: '3',
        name: 'Ron'
    },
    {
        parentId: '2',
        id: '4',
        name: 'Voldemort'
    },
    {
        parentId: '2',
        id: '5',
        name: 'Snape'
    },
    {
        parentId: '8',
        id: '6',
        name: 'Hagrid'
    },
    {
        parentId: '6',
        id: '7',
        name: 'Dumbledore'
    },
    {
        parentId: '10',
        id: '8',
        name: 'Malfoy'
    },
    {
        parentId: '10',
        id: '9',
        name: 'Sirius Black'
    },
    {
        parentId: null,
        id: '10',
        name: ' JK Rowling'
    }
]
```

Right now hierarchy of this data source goes like this (with the parent being `JK Rowling`):

> JK Rowling -> Malfoy, Sirius Black, Hagrid, Dumbledore, Harry, Hermoine, Ron, Voldemort, Snape

I have to reduce it to a new array with a specific parent id and all its children. Say, if I pass id `6` (parent becoming `Hagrid`) it should return me array like:

> Hagrid -> Dumbledore, Harry, Hermoine, Ron, Voldemort, Snape

Solution with O(nˆ2) complexity is available [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIhgewHKYCYoDeAUMmcgA5xQTip4D8AXMgM5hSgDmANKecDwt2nEL35kQcALYRhHbsQC+xYgkwh2yPHDBwW6LLgIBtALrIAvMhMTkJco8rVaYeiwDkAdg98nAoWQPAEZfO0cpWU8ACWooAE8POyU-cgd-Zxo6QO8wjORBTwAmPIzIuSDo6GlMUAgkxxS7dP8qLLccn1T-QqCAZlL-cs8AJQ0G8ibHFqc213cgku6nXo8AFkGnYaCANUwAGwIaqDAJsim08PI57OLNx1WAVnvybY8AZSkKeuTlmccbh1PAAOF5kVYANjByDesS4nDwZ2QFzI-2uLluQShywenWhbwAIgBXaQAI32EDwmBoSJR9iuZEBCxCAAZoatQTjXjIKh4ALJwfZYRK-ZoMzLzHLBNlc8E5ACc+J5nnewE4RNYyAAQvtEABrWl-cVMwJEkAEGB1PCygpSmXit7IABSAGlkGMAO77bi04hmVQwM0IMDADTILgQMAAYQAFsBDsYIKwABSAgwYHD4CA8ZCC-aJ1jpoxZ8wASnpZHUmjAMIgHtj8bwmuseYLADpLftIFBkyAs1YAHwwrNtk1WSzWQFtwSlgDc-GAMGQvbrDcOrDbFLEYBj5ZmIFXcfXo41MeTbYvB-rR6bHd1YAFFGTCBvg-DkbXeALz5vOdbWdYUsgPnRwaDAIkoBAWtr0bVgQORfgwIgqDzHnFRiEDEBg1DKCaDwIkkALAAVTBP3oXsAKLTNTDMHNehEbg934KstCvAsqMTcwrBsMx4JYmsrwABQxMBE24vsCA3S1zWTVxgDAeI3zkhTpzwcdrBneDF2XISRLEgBCCdkDNC0rSYiI63bChTxXD1hPaRM5zsNiAJPVgzwvNsI2jG9v10hysxzCSk2A-gVDIJDIOggs0NUAB6OLkH45A8IIykC241LCIAkiyLwZMdD0HNWQ8csAFoKrKocRkjZDNTzYdJLUDQtCy9KAMyyk0uI0ib3Iwq4GKqFS2azQDggTdMC4ZM2q-ADSyAA).

Note: Sorting order of the new array doesn't matter.

Was wondering if it could be done in O(n).

Comment: What makes you think it can be done in O(n)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve linear time complexity, you'll need a hashmap that provides O(1) (amortised) time complexity for insertion and lookup.

The idea is to first convert the tree information into an adjacency list where an entry is keyed by `id`. Once you have that adjacency list, you can drill down recursively to find all descendants of a given id.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function buildAdjacencyList(data) {
    // Create objects with children property, and key them by id
    const adj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.id, { ...o, children: [] }]));
    // Add a sentinel entry for having the root as child
    adj[null] = { children: [] };
    // Populate the children arrays based on parent relationships
    for (const o of data) adj[o.parentId].children.push(o.id);
    return adj;
}

function * descendants(adj, id) {
    yield adj[id].name;
    for (let childId of adj[id].children) {
        yield * descendants(adj, childId)
    }
}

// Demo
const data = [ { parentId: '7', id: '1', name: 'Harry' }, { parentId: '7', id: '2', name: 'Hermoine' }, { parentId: '7', id: '3', name: 'Ron' }, { parentId: '2', id: '4', name: 'Voldemort' }, { parentId: '2', id: '5', name: 'Snape' }, { parentId: '8', id: '6', name: 'Hagrid' }, { parentId: '6', id: '7', name: 'Dumbledore' }, { parentId: '10', id: '8', name: 'Malfoy' }, { parentId: '10', id: '9', name: 'Sirius Black' }, { parentId: null, id: '10', name: ' JK Rowling' } ];

const adj = buildAdjacencyList(data);
for (const name of descendants(adj, '6')) {
    console.log(name);
}
```